# HDMI-1 disconnected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, lenovo, hdmi

My machine is a Lenovo s145 and I'm not be able to use two monitors.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and Ubuntu 21.04 and I have the same error on both.

My problem is that HDMI shows disconnected in the `xrandr` command.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm 
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I changed the display manager to `lightDM` instead of `gdm3` with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

I configured manually the monitor with:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00 --right-of eDP-1
```

The image appears on the second monitor, but does not display correctly.

The image below shows: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQMUA.jpg)

Comment: It maybe a typo, but there were no releases in 2021-March (ie. 21.03) so either you're not using Ubuntu (thus why 21.03) or it's a typo. If you used an ISO with the HWE stack for 20.04, then results would be somewhat expected with 20.04 with HWE (ie. 5.11 kernel) & 21.04 (5.11 kernel), but you weren't more specific (eg. 20.04 using GA stack will differ much more as it'll be the 2020-April release stack)

Comment: It's a typo, I'm using 21.04. How I can more specific? I'm begginer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My cable is a problem!

My cable works when connecting another notebook (Lenovo Yoga 520 with Ubuntu 20.04), but when I connected my notebook (Lenovo s145 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu 21.04) it doesn't recognize the second monitor. I don't know why this happens, but when I changed the HDMI cable the Lenovo s145 recognized to the second monitor.

Cable that worked with Lenovo s145: DEX H AWM 2919 VM-1 80°C 30V VM-1 LOW VOLTAGE COMPUTER CABLE CPDZ

Cable that not worked with Lenovo s145: High speed HDMItm Cable with Ethernet AVM E494210-S STYLE 20276 80°C 30V VW-1 HWASUNG